# Howto disable mod_deflate compression from within a mod_perl script

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl, mod-deflate

I'm developing a web application running on Apache that is generating content in Perl scripts (mod_perl) and the output is being compressed with mod_deflate.

This works pretty well, but sometimes during the content generation the script notices that this page will not compress well and the final compression step should better be skipped.

mod_deflate is enabled by content type in the Apache configuration. Is it possible that the script eg. sets a flag or environment variable etc. that compression is disabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [mod_deflate docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html#enable):

"For browsers that have problems even with compression of all file types, use the BrowserMatch directive to set the no-gzip note for that particular browser so that no compression will be performed."

Setting the 'no-gzip' environment var looks like it will do the trick.

Comment: $ENV{'no-gzip'} = 1; indeed works to switch off the compression. Since I'm using mod_perl, would this newly set environment variable also affect other requests I'm processing (turning compression off when I still want it) ?

Comment: @GeneVincent -- I think so. Try `local $ENV{no_gzip} = 1;`.